# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'time_distributed_4' (type TimeDistributed)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I try to make CNN-LSTM model with Kvasir dataset. I split my dataset with `image_dataset_from_directory` as foloowing:

```
dataset_path = "/kaggle/working/dataset"
image_size = 224, 224
batch_size = 64

train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
  dataset_path,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  label_mode="categorical",
  seed=23,
  image_size=image_size,
  color_mode ="rgb",
  batch_size=batch_size)


val_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
  dataset_path,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  label_mode="categorical",
  seed=23,
  image_size=image_size,
  color_mode="rgb",
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

And this function gave me a BatchDataset. Then I make Cardinality as following:

```
val_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(val_ds)
test_ds = val_ds.take(val_batches // 2)
val_ds = val_ds.skip(val_batches // 2)
```

And then

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

And also this code gave me a Prefetch Dataset. It give when I run `print(train_ds)` :

```
<_PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

Then I added my model,

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Convolutional layers with batch normalization and max pooling
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=None,input_shape=(224, 224,3))),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),

    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=None)),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),



    # Flatten the output and add Dense layers
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten()),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256,activation='tanh'),
    
    
    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

    # Output layer with 8 nodes for classification
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model

model.compile(optimizer=AdamW(learning_rate=0.001, weight_decay=0.004, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8),
          loss=CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It didn't run when I fit this model and I got an error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'time_distributed_4' (type TimeDistributed).
    
    Input 0 of layer "conv2d_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 224, 3)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'time_distributed_4' (type TimeDistributed):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

I don't know how to overcome this problem, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

`Conv2D` already expects a 3D input (without the batch dim), and you have a 3D shape `(224, 224, 3)` in your dataset. When you wrap the layer in a `TimeDistributed` layer, it expects the first non-batch dimension (the first `224`) to be the time dimension for the `TimeDistributed` layer to strech along, and the rest of the input shape goes to the `Conv2D` layer.
This is why you get an error with `Full shape received: (None, 224, 3)`. Do you see how it changed from  the `(None, 224, 224, 3)` of the dataset? The  `Conv2D` layer did not receive the full `(None, 224, 224, 3)` shape anymore.

I'm not familiar with the dataset, but is there a good reason to use the `TimeDistributed` layer? If yes, you have to somehow transform the dataset to have an additional time axis. If no, discard the layers (not the layers they wrap around).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried a few different method. But finally I changed loading method for my dataset. I have done as following:

```
path = "/content/kvasir-dataset-v2/"
categories = next(os.walk(path))[1]
X , Y = [] , []
count = 0
for category in categories:
    ids = next(os.walk(path + category))[2]
    for i in ids:
        img = cv2.imread(path + category + '/' + i)
        img_resized = cv2.resize(img,(128,128), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        img_rsd_normalized = img_resized / 255.0
        X.append(img_rsd_normalized)
        Y.append(count)
    count += 1
```

And It runs now. Thank you for your support.